# R Extract partially matching string

Tags: r, regex

I have a question about extracting a part of a string from several files that has these rows:

units = specified
- name 0 = prDM: Pressure, Digiquartz [db] 
- name 1 = t090C: Temperature [ITS-90, deg C] 
- name 2 = c0S/m: Conductivity [S/m] 
- name 3 = t190C:Temperature, 2 [ITS-90, deg C] 
- name 4 = c1S/m: Conductivity, 2 [S/m]
- name 5 = flSP: Fluorescence, Seapoint 
- name 6 = sbeox0ML/L: Oxygen, SBE 43 [ml/l] 
- name 7 = altM: Altimeter [m] 
- name 8 = sal00: Salinity, Practical [PSU] 
- name 9 = sal11: Salinity, Practical, 2 [PSU] 
- span 0 =      1.000,     42.000

I need to extract only the information of the columns that start with "name" and  extract everything between = and: .
For example, in the row "name 0 = prDM: Pressure, Digiquartz [db]" the desired result will be prDM. 
Some files have different number of "name"rows (i.e. this example has 13 rows but other files has 16, and the number varies), so I want it to be as general as I can so I can allways extract the right strings independently the number of rows.Rows starts with # and a space before name. 
I have tried this code but it only extract the first row. Can you please help me with this? Many thanks!

```
CNV<-NULL
for (i in 1:nro.files){
x <- readLines(all.files[i])
name.col<-grep("^\\# name", x) 
df <- data.table::fread(text = x[name.col])
CNV[[i]]<-df
}
```

Comment: Try [`name[^=]+=\s([^:]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/ED2jSB/1)

Comment: I get this Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "" name[^=]+=\s"

Comment: Try `\\s` instead.

Comment: I did but still only extract the first row...

Comment: Your string in file is a single line? All these rows are one after another?

Comment: @SrdjanM. all of these rows are one after another

Comment: I've updated my answer as to your comment about only wanting the `name =` strings taken.

Comment: Like this [`demo`](https://rextester.com/YDY85487)

Comment: here is one file as an example:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/uq402dl22lingfo/CT01.cnv?dl=0

Comment: After you extract all matches from `str_match_all` you need to make another `for loop` were you will read data from your table `data.table::fread(text = x[result[[1]][[i,2]]])` [demo](https://rextester.com/YPVYMO85771)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `stringr` and the regex pattern `"name \\d+ = (.*?):"` which means in words "name followed by one or more digits followed by an equals sign followed by a space followed by a captured group containing any character (the period) zero or more times (the *) followed by a colon".

```
   library(stringr)
    strings <- c("name 0 = prDM: Pressure, Digiquartz [db]",
    "name 1 = t090C: Temperature [ITS-90, deg C]",
    "name 2 = c0S/m: Conductivity [S/m]",
    "name 3 = t190C:Temperature, 2 [ITS-90, deg C]",
    "name 4 = c1S/m: Conductivity, 2 [S/m]",
    "name 5 = flSP: Fluorescence, Seapoint",
    "name 6 = sbeox0ML/L: Oxygen, SBE 43 [ml/l]",
    "name 7 = altM: Altimeter [m]",
    "name 8 = sal00: Salinity, Practical [PSU]",
    "name 9 = sal11: Salinity, Practical, 2 [PSU]")

    result <- str_match(strings, "name \\d+ = (.*):")
    result[,2]
 [1] "prDM"       "t090C"      "c0S/m"      "t190C"      "c1S/m"      "flSP"       "sbeox0ML/L"
 [8] "altM"       "sal00"      "sal11"
```

Or if you prefer `base`

```
pattern = "name \\d+ = (.*):"
result <- regmatches(strings, regexec(pattern, strings))
sapply(result, "[[", 2)

 [1] "prDM"       "t090C"      "c0S/m"      "t190C"      "c1S/m"      "flSP"       "sbeox0ML/L"
 [8] "altM"       "sal00"      "sal11"
```

Comment: that can be usefull, thanks! but my problem is that I have other columns that has = and :  but i only need the ones that has the string "name" following by a number

Comment: @CarlaBerghoff I'm not sure what your question is - please provide a reproducible example and your expected output per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

If you just need to make sure the original string contains "name" you can add it to the regex `result <- str_match(strings, "name \\d = (.*):")`

Comment: here is one file as an example: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uq402dl22lingfo/CT01.cnv?dl=0

Comment: @CarlaBerghoff  please read the first answer in the linked post in my comment above and produce an example like the post describes.

Comment: it does not work... I get the full first row that start with "name and get this warning: 1: In data.table::fread(text = x[result]) :
  Stopped early on line 3. Expected 2 fields but found 1. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line: <<# name 2 = c0S/m: Conductivity [S/m]>>

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_extract` from package `stringr` and positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
str <- "name 0 = prDM: Pressure, Digiquartz [db]"

str_extract(str, "(?<== ).*(?=:)")
[1] "prDM"
```

Explanation:

`(?<== )`if you see `=`followed by white space on the left (lookbehind)

`.*` match anything until ...

`(?=:)`... you see a colon on the right (lookahead)

Comment: since other columns contains = and :, and I only want to extract the string in the ones that start with name, could you help me to adapt the code? I am so lost! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a few examples of these "other" strings?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have other strings that also contain `=` and `:`but which do not start with `name`and from which you do not wish to extract anything.--right? Something like this: `str <- c("name 0 = prDM: Pressure, Digiquartz [db]","blahblah X = blaBLah: blahblah usw.","name 1 = t090C: Temperature [ITS-90, deg C]")`

Answer (score 0):

In Base R

```
test <- c("name 0 = prDM: Pressure, Digiquartz [db]","name 1 = t090C: Temperature [ITS-90, deg C]")

gsub("^name [0-9]+ = (.+):.+","\\1",test)

[1] "prDM"  "t090C"
```

explanation

`^name [0-9]+` Searches for a the beginning of a string `^` with name folowed by any length of number

`= (.+):` any length `+` of any character `.` found between  `=` and `:` are stored `( )`  to be later recalled by `\\1`